# How do I start a project on Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud, magento-cloud

I would like to know how can I create a project on https://accounts.magento.cloud?

for example like the image:

[image]

I couldn't find any about it.

Answer (score 0):

Offical document will help you:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/project/overview.html?lang=en

Also, remember the "Support Tickets" tab helps you in other ways.